# How do you align text to bottom left in card-body

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller

I'm using bootstrap 5in an MVC application and trying to align text to bottom left. The text should be aligned to bottom left when you hover over a card to see extra info.
However I try I can't seem to make it work.

```
@for (var j = 0; j
< 3 && i + j < arrivaltestresult.Count; j++) { <div class="col-4 p-0 text-center">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350" class="card-img-top" alt="...">


    <div class="card-body text-light text-start text-left bottom-align-text">
      <div class="display-flex">
        <h5>@arrivaltestresult[i+j].Name</h5>

        <div class="extra-info mt-auto">
          <p>@arrivaltestresult[i+j].Category</p>
          <p class="@(@arrivaltestresult[i+j].DiscountPrice > 0 ? " text-decoration-line-through " :"d-none ")">@arrivaltestresult[i+j].Price</p>
          <p class="price-text">@(@arrivaltestresult[i+j].DiscountPrice > 0 ? @arrivaltestresult[i+j].DiscountPrice: @arrivaltestresult[i+j].Price)</p>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  first = false; }
```

[image]

I've added a picture to show how it looks currently.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: do you have any example or site that has something like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
style="margin-left:0px;margin-botton:0px"
```